# How do I identify the "sudo ... " command output format?

Tags: io-redirection

I am enclosing bash -x output which shows that the command "sudo iwlist wlan0 scan" was executed and returned expected text to terminal . 
The issue is - this text was not passed to whiptail msgbox option.

This fails with other "sudo ... " commands, and only with "sudo .. commands. 
My guess is there are non printing characters in the output text causing this issue.

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

whiptail --title 'Command sudo iwlist wlan0 scan output 1400'       -   -separate-output --scrolltext --msgbox '' 17 80 10
```

Comment: I like to totally rebuild my question - is that OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are not sure, try redirecting the stdout then stderr to /dev/null.
For example, with `lsusb -h > /dev/null` you can still see the output, whereas with `lsusb -h 2> /dev/null` there's not output - therefore, the output of the help goes to stderr.
If you want to redirect stderr to stdout:
`lsusb -h 2>&1`
It's not obvious (at first) but what this command does is redirect stderr (file descriptor #2) to stdout (file descriptor #1).

Comment: lsusb -h > /dev/null you can still see the output yes I do in terminal and it locks it up I need to see it on screen "stdout"

Comment: Actually I see all on terminal, the variable is passed to whiptail which I need to redirect.

Comment: Well, without any additional information from your part, it's going to be hard to help you! ;)

The example below works, but I don't know how well it would fit into your script: 
`whiptail --msgbox "$(lsusb 2>&1)" 20 80`

Comment: What other info do you need?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what your script does, or how it works. This makes it hard to be relevant. From what I understand, you want some variable to hold both the stdout and stderr output of the `lsudb` command.

For example: `var=$(lsusb -h 2>&1)` The variable `var` will hold both stdout and stderr; you can then use it with whiptail: `whiptail --msgbox "${var}" 20 80`

Comment: I was hoping the post title was explanatory. The solution is indeed in proper redirection.SOLVED